# Controller hangs when opened using url in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm new on asp.net mvc. I created a basic controller and I tried to open it using url. But rendering is not finished and my controller didn't display in several minutes. I did not change anything from default asp.net 5 mvc project also my controller's index method return only hello world string. I don't is there any problem on iis or VS. Any idea about that problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is way too little info. Give us some code or link to this "default project".

Comment: Post some code and give your folder structure as well with the files in them (views and controllers).

Comment: You can use pastebin or a gist

Comment: public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // GET: HelloWorld
        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is <b>Index</b> action...";
        }

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is my  welcome method";
        }

Comment: I am trying to open this controller. I don't use any view for that and I have no idea why this not render

Comment: Can you please give more info about the folder structure and the url you are using? It's diffucult to help you without any info.

Comment: Did you debug already?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC only *public* methods that return an `ActionResult` are accessible as web pages.

So you MUST use something like this:

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    // GET: HelloWorld/Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("This is <b>Index</b> action...");
    }
    // etc
}
```

`Content(...)` is a special method the wraps text into an `ActionResult`.

Note: only use `Content(...)` if you specifically do NOT want to use a View such as Index.cshtml - which is what you normally WOULD do, of course.